# How to invoke the UIWebview's delegate method?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

the Question :

how to invoke the UIWebview's delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView 
        shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Please show me all of the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Step

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate>

@end
```

then set Delegate of your `UIWebview` to self

```
self..webview.delegate = self
```

then implement method you need

Answer (score 2):

If you have set your UIWebView to an IBOutlet, you can do this in your `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
myWebView.delegate = self
```

Then, whenever anything happens in the web view, your delegate method in your view controller will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and IBOutlet for webview and can set it's delegate like `self.webview.delegate=self` or you can set the delegate from Interface Builder by clicking and dragging from UIWebview to the Yellow icon on your view controller.